# Error “Specified element is already the logical child of another element”? - Root Cause

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've no idea where is this coming from. Following is the complete stack trace in debug mode. How to find the root cause?

Following stack trace doesn't say much about the Source of the error, and inner exception is null sadly.

```
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ChangeLogicalParent(DependencyObject newParent)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.AddLogicalChild(Object child)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.OnContentChanged(Object oldContent, Object newContent)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.OnContentChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.PropertyChangedCallback.Invoke(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.CoerceValue(DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridHelper.TransferProperty(DependencyObject d, DependencyProperty p)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader.PrepareColumnHeader(Object item, DataGridColumn column)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, Object item)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.MS.Internal.Controls.IGeneratorHost.PrepareItemContainer(DependencyObject container, Object item)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.IItemContainerGenerator.PrepareItemContainer(DependencyObject container)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellsPanel.InsertContainer(Int32 childIndex, UIElement container, Boolean isRecycled)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellsPanel.AddContainerFromGenerator(Int32 childIndex, UIElement child, Boolean newlyRealized)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellsPanel.GenerateChild(IItemContainerGenerator generator, Size constraint, DataGridColumn column, Int32& childIndex, Size& childSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellsPanel.DetermineRealizedColumnsBlockList(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellsPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.InvokeOnRenderCallback.DoWork()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.Resize(ICompositionTarget resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.OnResize()
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

Update1: The issue was fixed by using

```
HeaderTeamplate = {StaticResource BALimitedHeaderTemplate}
```

Instead of

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
  <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource BALimitedHeaderTemplate}"   x:Name="_BAContentPresenter"/>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
```

Lines above with ContentPresenter are part of a user control that is added dynamically to a Parent window multiple times. I am still not sure, why adding the user control (seperate instances) to the window is causing the exception though - and more strangely only in .Net framework 4.0 **but not in 4.5 and above.**

**Update 2:** Apparently it's a bug in Framework V4.0, and usage seems pretty legitimate. This issue is fixed in Framework 4.5 and Above! We worked around this using HeaderTemplate. Someone else has tried to describe this problem in following link.

http://impulsecode.blogspot.sg/2012/01/in-wpf-getting-error-specified-element.html

Comment: You are manually attempting to add a visual item to another window or control collection that already has a window or control collection assigned to it

Comment: This exception is only coming on couple of machines in production - rest all machines are working great.

Comment: I just updated framework to 4.5 (from original 4.0) on the machine where this issue persited, and after framework update it's gone.

Comment: That's nice. It's still caused by what I said. Now with the added complexity of a race condition

Comment: Don't understand the race condition part. How does that come in picture with framework 4.5 update?

Comment: Great question. Unfortunately with zero code posted and clearly some type of production application being discussed, I'm not sure how you can expect me or anyone to answer that. However, that error is caused by what I said. If it's only on certain machines then its likely a race condition.

Comment: I Understand - it should not be a race condition (at least from my code). Just meant- all the machines reporting this machine have framework 4.0 installed, and ones not reporting this have 4.5 installed. Reason why I can't post code is because I still don't know the area of code throwing this exception. This is reported from dispatched unhandled exception and stack trade doesn't have enough information (Except that it originated in presentationframework)

Comment: That was the longest winded 'It works on my machine' I've ever read lol.

Comment: Check which control has changed by using the `Call hierarchy`window of visual studio on line 3/4 of your call stack. Once you identified the control you can probably solve the problem or provide us some more information

Comment: Thanks Markus - Added my comments to my question.

Comment: @Anthony Russell - I am sure your next assumption was going to be more bizarre "Ah this problem is because of a data base connection pool fragmentation" - Just because there was no code. Never the less, you were trying to help - So thank you so much for that!